# Linear Algebra - subspaces and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant

> Check wether S is a vectorial subspace of V: $V = M_{2}(\mathbb{R}) $ and $ S = ${ $ A$ ∈ $M_{2}(\mathbb{R}): A$ is invertible}

I understood that it is not a subspace because for A to be invertible then $det A ≠ 0 $, then there is no null vector, therefore S can't be a subspace

But I did not understand the notations of the question, like $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: $M_2(\mathbb R)$ means $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right and, as noticed in the comments, we are dealing with the set of square matrices of order $2$ with real entries, often denoted also by $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$.